# Creating dynamic filter report in salesforce .want to get results in the same page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, dynamic-visualforce, ajax

```
<apex:page > 
<html>
    <form method="get" action="https://cs6.salesforce.com/00ON0000000FOHS" >
        <b>Enter Text</b><input type="text" id="pv2" name="pv2"/>
        <input type="button" value="Report Generation" class="button" onclick="samepage();"/>
   </form>
<script>
Function samepage()
{
Var text =Document.getElementById("pv2").value;
Var Data= text;
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://cs6.salesforce.com/00ON0000000FOHS" // form action url
      data: Data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(output)
      {
Document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= output;
      }     
      });
}
</script>
This dynamic div
<div id="output" style="border:1px solid;width:1000px;height:500px;">
</div>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

I need in such a way that half of the page will be static and another half of the page will be dynamic .will change according to user input

for this i had wrote one page it is not returning the div tag?

when i keep input type as submit it resulting the results in new window?
i need that in the same page .how can i do that is this the correct way?
help me out

Comment: Hi,u can use <apex:actionfunction/> for this one

Comment: And one more thing u r forgot to include JQuery as u r using $.ajax....also u r using same url as u mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case, there's really no need to use jquery async call (at least not in the terms of 'manually' building your async request; solution using commandButton will still generate async request 'under the hood', but you won't need to handcode it). My suggestion would be to use **custom controller** in combination with **apex:outputPanel** refreshed upon each call to **apex:commandButton's** action (specified through commandButton's **rerender** attribute).

In this case your VF page might look something like:

```
<apex:page controller="YourReportPageController" > 
    <apex:form >
        <b>Enter Text</b>

        <apex:inputText id="pv2" value="{!pv2Text}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Report Generation" action="{!generateReport}" rerender="reportOutputDiv" />

        This dynamic div
        <apex:outputPanel id="reportOutputDiv" layout="block" style="border:1px solid;width:1000px;height:500px;">
            <apex:outputText value="{!htmlOutput}" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
   </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

...with **YourReportPageController** looking like this:

```
public with sharing class YourReportPageController
{
    public string pv2Text { get; set; }
    public string htmlOutput { get; set; }

    public YourReportPageController()
    {
        // whatever logic you need to do on load
    }

    public PageReference generateReport()
    {
        // do whatever you need to do to generate report
        // ...
        // if you need to use value from the inputField,
        // simply access it via pv2Text variable

        // Assign report output value to htmlOutput variable
        htmlOutput = "bla bla";

        // return null in order to avoid redirect (stay on the same page)
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.